# How to sed and put back the part of the match?

Tags: sed

So these are the original texts:

```
$ printf 'bbb\nb2b\n'
bbb
b2b
```

This is what I'm doing

```
$ printf 'bbb\nb2b\n' | sed 's/^b[0-9]/XXX/g'
bbb
XXXb
```

And this is the output that I want :D

```
$ printf 'bbb\nb2b\n' | SOME_SED_MAGIC
bbb
XXX2b
```

**My question**: How can I swap the "b2b" to "XXX2b", so I put back the "2" from the sed match? "2" could vary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `backreference`:

```
$ printf 'bbb\nb2b\n' | sed 's/^b\([0-9]\)/XXX\1/'
bbb
XXX2b
```

<sup>(BTW, you don't need the `g`  flag since that regex can match only once because of the `^`).</sup>